# Is there only one way to export file in mvc view?I use location.href but the url parameter is too long

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

In my controller I return a file,it is OK.But in the view,I use `location.href=url`,sometimes if the url parameter is too long,I can not download the file.Is the max length of url is 1024B?How to solve the solve the question if the question if the url parameter is too long?Must I change the view code,or change the iis config?

**MVC View function**

```
  //studentName may be very long
  function GetFile(){
      var searchCondiction = {
                studentName: $("#studentName").val(),
                startDate: $("#UploadYear").val(),
            };
     location.href = "@Url.Action("GetFile", "Student")?" + $.param(searchCondiction );
    }
```

**MVC Controller function**

```
public ActionResult GetFile(string studentName,DateTime startDate)
{
//Product file according to  studentName and startDate
...
//Return file
Return File(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/UserA/a.png"),"imge/png");
}
```

Comment: this is a server issue IIS and not MVC, you need to ask question on serverfault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the url shorter. one way would be to store the parameters serverside, and just return a key.